# How do you install plugins for MacVim?

Tags: vim, macvim, nerdtree, vim-plugins

Specifically, I'm trying to install NERDtree. I downloaded the 4.10 package from [github](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree), unzipped it into `~/.vim/`, and restarted MacVim (version 7.3).

Typing `:nerdtree` results in the following error:

```
E492: Not an editor command: nerdtree
```

In terminal, typing:

```
cd ~/.vim
ls -R
```

Results in:

```
Rakefile    doc     nerdtree_plugin plugin

./doc:
NERD_tree.txt

./nerdtree_plugin:
exec_menuitem.vim   fs_menu.vim

./plugin:
NERD_tree.vim
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command is `:NERDTree`—case does matter, especially since only internal Vim commands can start with a lowercase letter.

If you followed the installation instructions you should be able to do "`:help NERD_Tree.txt`".  If not, do "`:helptags ~/.vim/doc`".

Comment: This was it. Thank you! I had also tried `NERDtree`, but I never tried it with a capital T. :\

Comment: @Closure Cowboy: that's still a lot to type. Typing ":NE" then hitting tab does the job for me, because vim has auto-completion in the command line.